# PHP: Accessing protected var from child class

Tags: php, class, parent-child, protected

I'm learning PHP and I'm stuck i the following code:

```
<?php

class dogtag {

    protected $Words;

}

class dog {

    protected $Name;
    protected $DogTag;

    protected function bark() {
        print "Woof!\n";
    }

}

class poodle extends dog {

    public function bark() {
        print "Yip!\n";
    }

}

$poppy = new poodle;
$poppy->Name = "Poppy";
$poppy->DogTag = new dogtag;
$poppy->DogTag->Words = "My name is
Poppy. If you find me, please call 555-1234";

var_dump($poppy);

?>
```

This is what I got:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot access protected property poodle::$Name
```

This looks strange to me as I should access protected vars and functions from child classes.

Could please someone explain where I'm wrong?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Protected variables can indeed be accessed from the child class. However you aren't accessing your variable from inside the child class.

If you make the variables `public` you can access them from outside the class.

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Example:

```
Class Dog {

   private $privateProperty = "private"; //I can only be access from inside the Dog class
   protected $protectedProperty = "protected"; //I can be accessed from inside the dog class and all child classes
   public $publicProperty = "public"; //I can be accessed from everywhere.

}


Class Poodle extends Dog {

   public function getProtectedProperty(){
       return $this->protectedProperty; //This is ok because it's inside the Poodle (child class);
   }

}

$poodle = new Poodle;
echo $poodle->publicProperty; //This is ok because it's public
echo $poodle->getProtectedProperty(); //This is ok because it calls a public method.
```

Comment: Thanks @Daan but I not sure I get it. You mean I'm trying to access it from an instance ($poppy) of the subclass and not from the sublass definition (class poodle extends...)?

Comment: It means you're not accessing it from inside the dog class but from the outside.

Comment: I'm very sorry but I don't understand. I'm trying to access $Name from the poodle subclass, which inherits from dog class. I create an instance of poodle ($poppy) and I try to change the protected var $Name. I understand I can't do this with a private var but $Name is protected. So as $poppy is an instance of poodle class, I should be able to modify the protected parent's var. Thanks for you patience.

Comment: I've added an example, hopefully this will clear things up.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand! Have a nice day.,

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the property 'Words', you need to make it public

Answer (score 0):

you could add `magic` methods to your class - that would allow you to access and manipulate the private properties from outside the class.

```
class foo{
    private $bah;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->bah='hello world';
    }
    public function __get( $name ){
        return $this->$name;
    }
    public function __set( $name,$value ){
        $this->$name=$value;
    }
    public function __isset( $name ){
        return isset( $this->$name );
    }
    public function __unset( $name ){
        unset( $this->$name );  
    }
}

$foo=new foo;
echo $foo->bah;

$foo->bah='banana';
echo $foo->bah;
```